# javaagent attach - Glassfish - javassist - class mismatch exception

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

I am using javaagent **attach** mechanism, and I would like to use **javassist** to instrument a method that imports a class from javax.servlet dependency (within a Glassfish application):

```
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
```

If I don't manually (whilst instrumenting the method) insert a classpath into the pool I get a NoClassDefFoundError error. My understanding is that this is caused by the **agent** code being unable to access this class for the purposes of re-compiling the instrumented method. To work around it I include the jar, within my **transform** method inside the agent:

```
pool.insertClassPath("/usr/glassfish/app/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar");
```

Now I can successfully instrument this class using **insertBefore** method.

However! If I try to access the first argument of the instrumented method not just as an object (I can convert it to string to see its class), but by casting it as a **ServletRequest** from the aforementioned servlet-api library I get a strange exception:

```
StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequest
        at my.reporting.agent.AgentCallback.logAction(AgentCallback.java:60)
```

The above suggests that the Agent callback is incapable of finding the class definition. 
But upon googling the Exception I found that it could also be caused by Agent and the Application referencing different dependencies. And that is the case (partly): my agent references the dependency from Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I then import this class in exactly the same way as the intrumented application does (listed above).

And the instrumented application appears to be using the bundled version of this jar:

```
Class loader: javax.servlet-api [166]
Resource: bundle://166.0:1/javax/servlet/Servlet...
```

I can't possibly think of a way to point my Agent to the bundled library within the Glassfish application. And if it isn't necessary, then what is going wrong here?

Comment: What do you use to do the actual bytecode transformation? Bytebuddy? ASM? Apache BCEL?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, thank you for pointing this out. I have edited the question to explain that I am using javassist

Comment: Did you try to add the class loader of the transformed class instead or the JAR? I am not very experienced with Javassist and with class-loading in general, but I remember that you can do something like that in Javassist. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful, BTW. I cannot compile your little code snippets and reproduce the situation.